# Function subtyping and Scala - confused

Tags: scala

So I'm getting a little confused with function subtyping.  I have the below that I'm messing around with.  I know that for contravariance, that A->Int is a subtype of B->Int which is why I was able to assign AToInt to "testBContra".

But what I thought I could do is pass an A object to "testBContra"...

testBContra(a)

which doesn't work.  Am I misunderstanding what can be passed in?  I thought that I could now pass an A object and have it return an Int.

```
class S(x: Int) {
  val sInput = x
}

class A(x: Int) extends S(x){
  val aInput = x
}

class B(x: Int) extends A(x){
  val bInput = x
}

def AToInt(h: A): Int = h.aInput

// Checking contravariance

// val testSContra: S=>Int = AtoInt
val testAContra: A=>Int = AToInt
val testBContra: B=>Int = AToInt

val a = new A(2)
val b = new B(5)
val s = new S(10)

testAContra(b)
testBContra(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testBContra` has type `B => Int`, but since `A` is not a subtype of `B` you can't evaluate `testBContra(a)`. The contravariance of function types is used when you assign a function `A => Int` to a value with type `B => Int` as you do in

```
val testBContra: B => Int = AToInt
```

The [Function1 trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) is contravariant in its parameter type and covariant in its result type. Contravariance means that if `A` is a supertype of `B` then a function `A => T` is a subtype of a function `B => T` for some result type `T`. Contravariance reverses direction of the super/sub-typing relationship. This means that if you have a function:

```
def foo(f: B => Int)
```

you can call it directly with `AtoInt` because `A => Int` is a subtype of `B => Int` i.e.

```
foo(AToInt)
```

without the contravariance of function parameters you would have to wrap `AToInt` in a function with an argument type of `B` i.e.

```
foo((b: B) => AToInt(b))
```

The covariance of function return types means that if `B` is a subtype of `A` then a function `T => B` is a subtype of `T => A` for some input type `T`. In your example, since `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal` and `Any`, `AToInt` is a subtype of `A => AnyVal` and `A => Any`. So if you had a function

```
def bar(f: A => AnyVal) = f(new A())
```

then you can call `bar(AToInt)`.

The two kinds of variance can be combined, so for example `AToInt` is also a subtype of `B => AnyVal` since `A` is a supertype of `B` and `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`.

Comment: Also it helps to look at what `testBContra` could do. Say it was `val testBContra: B => Int = _.bInput`. Then obviously the type system weren't sound if it allowed you to pass a value `a` of type `A` to it, because `a` does not have method `bInput`.

Comment: Thank you guys.  Sorry if I'm being dense about this.  It could be that I just wrote a poor example to work with but how then could I pass something to testBContra that would be of A => Int?  The function expects an object so when I try to pass it a function it returns an error

Comment: @cpd1 - Why are you assigning a function `A => Int` to a variable of type `B => Int` and then trying to call it with an instance of `A`? Can't you just call it directly? Could you add more detail to your question to show why you need to do this?

Comment: I am a little confused with this stuff so sorry if I'm not being clear but I just want to prove to myself that I can pass something of A=>Int to something of B=>Int.  I thought I could pass the object A but I realize that  I was just testing class subtyping instead of function subtyping.  It just seems to me that I haven't done much that will make testBContra work any differently after assigning the type A=>Int to the function.

Comment: @cpd1 - You already are assigning a function `A => Int` to one with type `B => Int` when you assign `testBContra`. The difference between `testBContra` and `AToInt` is that you are narrowing the parameter type from `A` to one of its subtypes `B`. That is the reason you can't pass an `A` to `testBContra` even though you can to the underlying method. This isn't that useful on its own but is if you have some function `foo(f: B => Int)` you need to call when you already have a function `A => Int` as you do here. Then you can do `foo(AToInt)` instead of `foo(b: B => AToInt(b))`

Comment: Thanks for following up!  So foo is actually illustrating function subtyping right?  So `foo(AToInt)` works because `A => Int` is actually a subtype of `B=>Int`?  I then tried to set up another function `def foo2(f: S=>Int): Int = 1` and then `foo2(AToInt)` but this won't work because `A=>Int` is not a subtype to `S=>Int`?

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried it with covariance as well and that seems to confirm what I was thinking.  This helps me a bit so thank you

Comment: @cpd1 - It's not `foo` itself which illustrates function subtyping but rather calling `foo` with a function `A => Int` which is a subtype of `B => Int`. I've added a more detail explanation.